# How to find and replace data in an mp3 file ID3 tag header

Tags: ruby

How can I do a find replace on an .mp3 file to replace a certain part of the ID3 tag?
My code so far is as follows:

```
path = 'path_to_my_mp3_file.mp3'
new_path = 'new_path.mp3'
File.open path do |file|
    content = file.read
    content.gsub! 'wrong_album_name', 'correct_album_name' 
    File.new(new_path, 'w+') do |f|
        f.write content
    end
end
```

I am getting invalid byte sequence error.  I'm also wondering since I know the exact position and length of byte I need to replace how I can just rewrite that in the original file.

Comment: `mp3` is a binary file. You need to be using `binread`. Also, if the name you're replacing isn't exactly the same length, it may not be as simple as substituting and writing out the new name. You need to study the header structure of an `mp3` and make sure you take care of header offsets and padding that may change as a result of changing that field. But rather than do all that yourself, you should consider using a Ruby gem to help, such as [id3tag](https://rubygems.org/gems/id3tag).

Comment: I am doing this more as sort of an exercise so I rather not use any gems.

Comment: OK, then see my other comments. Do a Google search on "mp3 id3 format"  or "mp3 header format" or something similar. You'll need to understand the mp3 header structure before you can change anything in there without corrupting the file. And in Ruby, you need to do binary reads/writes rather than text (your current code is using text). Here's a potentially [useful link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8295/MPEG-Audio-Frame-Header).